# JS->Form validation on inputs. Using for loop to get all the inputs index

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form with 4 inputs and I want to show an alert on submit. What I have done is that I have already created the warnings that goes under every input with display:none; in CSS.

After this I have created a for loop in JS to get the index of every input and apply my if statement of showing the the alert if === null || === "" 
using a variable to make the `querySelector("THE CLASS").style.display="block";`

Also on my form I have this line

`<form method="post" class="q-form" name="form" onsubmit="return validate()">`

My problem is when I submit my form the only alert that is shown is the one under the Username and after it appears it also disappears because I think that the for loop goes to the next input.

Let me know if there is something more to clarify.

Here you have all the code: https://jsbin.com/kazopahuga/1/edit?html,js,output

If you want to see the alert showing press Run with JS

Thank You!

Comment: Please post the relevant snippets of code here, not just as a link to jsbin.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a few modifications to your `validare()` function:

Add a flag indicating whether the whole form is valid, assume it's true until you find an input that is invalid.  Return the value of this flag.

`var isValid = true;`

Capture your validation messages too so you can access them by index like your inputs:

`messages = document.getElementsByClassName(' alert alert-danger custom');`

When you find an invalid input, display the associated message and update the valid flag to false.

```
if (currentInputValue == null || currentInputValue === "") {
    messages[index].style.display = "block";
    isValid = false;
}
```

Here is the updated function:

```
function validare() {

    var inputs, messages, index;
    var isValid = true;

    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    messages = document.getElementsByClassName(' alert alert-danger custom');

    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        var currentInputValue = inputs[index].value;
        if (currentInputValue == null || currentInputValue === "") {
            messages[index].style.display = "block";
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

[Updated jsbin here](https://jsbin.com/wihebiqufu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I have used your version of the function and I added a small else to hide my alerts if the conditions are not met.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated solution: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/piqasufemo/edit?html,js,console,output)

You used querySelector which return only the first element it finds with the same class, you should have used querySelectorAll which return all the selectors.

Comment: Ok. I have implemented you changes and I can see how this is working. Also I have change the onsubmit to onchange in order to keep the alerts showing. They don`t disappear after I input a valid value.