# Validation Form using For loop and InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I need to create a form that contains the following; name, surname, email, telephone number.
through javascript with a for loop I have to make sure that all the fields have been filled in and if not, write with an innerHTML "error" next to the missing field.
I have to use 'document.forms [x]. [x]' and perform element checking through a 'for' loop.
In the end, I have to enter the privacy consent through a checkbox to be selected compulsorily.
If all fields have been entered according to the criteria required it must redirect to [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

This is the malfunctioning code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>

<link href="base_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="convalida.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <label><strong>Compila il form</strong></label>
  
  <form id="form1">
   
    <label>Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    
    <br><br>
    
    <label>Cognome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
   
    <br><br>
   
    <label>E-mail: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
   
    <br><br>
   
    <label>N° Matricola: </label>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    
    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="privacy" name="privacy" required> accept privacy condition
    <input type="submit" onClick="controllo_convalida()">
      
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
function controllo_convalida(){
  var controllo = false;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < (document.forms[0].elements.length)-1; i++) {
    if (document.forms[0].elements[i].value == "" ) {
      controllo = false;
      alert("Compila tutti i campi del form!");
    }
    
        
    if (controllo == true) {
      document.forms[0].action = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
      document.forms[0].submit();
      var x = document.getElementById("privacy").required;
      document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you can't add the attribute `required` in the html, and let the browser perform the validation?

Comment: I have to follow the contents of the description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233301/js-form-validation-on-inputs-using-for-loop-to-get-all-the-inputs-index